# Using a string as a name of an attribute of a class in C#

Tags: c#, variables, reflection, attributes, field

the question probably already has been answered, but i honestly dont know what to search for, an "Reflection" did not solve my issue.

I want to call a field by a string such as:

```
    string str = "Green";
    Color colorForPurpose = Color.str;
```

Of course this does not work, but the purpose should be clear.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Winforms? [Color.FromName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you asking *in general* or specifically about `Color`? I ask because the answer to your question highly depends on this distinction.

Comment: What are you trying to access a field or enum? An attribute of a class is completely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
string str = "Green";
Color colorForPurpose = Color.FromName(str)
```

See [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information.

Comment: If this post was helpful, PLEASE mark it as answer.